# Getting error running terraform apply for elastictranscoder

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-elastic-transcoder

Error message:

```
Error: Error creating Elastic Transcoder Pipeline: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post "https://elastictranscoder.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/2012-09-25/pipelines": dial tcp: lookup elastictranscoder.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host

  on ../../modules/backend_v2/video_transcoder_lambda_pipeline.tf line 35, in resource "aws_elastictranscoder_pipeline" "backend_elastictranscoder":
  35: resource "aws_elastictranscoder_pipeline" "backend_elastictranscoder" {
```

How can I handle/debug this error message?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the `elastictranscoder` is not available in `eu-central-1`.

Per March 2022 `elastictranscoder` is only available in: `us-east-1, us-west-1, us-west-2, ap-south-1, ap-southeast-1, ap-southeast-2, ap-northeast-1, eu-west-1`